# Downshift in Reactjs - Menu dropdown only displaying selected item

Tags: reactjs, downshift

> Im having trouble using `Downshift`, Initially I have all the menu
>   options but once I select one option, thats the only one
>   that shows in the menu the next time I click on it.

[image]

> This is my current code, any feedback on whats causing that?

```
const dropdownItems = [
  { value: 'All' },
  { value: 'Database A' },
  { value: 'Database B' },
  { value: 'Database C' },
  { value: 'Database D' },
];
return (
  <Downshift itemToString={item => (item ? item.value : '')}>
    {({
      getMenuProps,
      getItemProps,
      getToggleButtonProps,
      getRootProps,
      isOpen,
      inputValue,
      selectedItem,
      highlightedIndex,
    }) => console.log(
      selectedItem === null ? dropdownItems[0].value : selectedItem.value,
    ) || (
        <Container {...getRootProps()}>
          <button {...getToggleButtonProps()}>
            {isOpen
              ? selectedItem === null
                ? dropdownItems[0].value
                : selectedItem.value
              : selectedItem === null
                ? dropdownItems[0].value
                : selectedItem.value}
          </button>
          {isOpen ? (
            <Menu {...getMenuProps()}>
              {dropdownItems
                .filter(
                  item => !inputValue || item.value.includes(inputValue),
                )
                .map((item, index) => (
                  <Item
                    {...getItemProps({
                      key: item.value,
                      index,
                      item,
                      style: {
                        fontWeight:
                          index === highlightedIndex
                            ? 'bold'
                            : null,
                      },
                    })}
                  >
                    {item.value}
                  </Item>
                ))}
            </Menu>
          ) : null}
        </Container>
      )
    }
  </Downshift>
);
```

Comment: it is your button tag, specifically the selectedItem === null conditional which is causing it. As soon as you select dbB once, selectedItem is not null anymore and it displays its value in the dropdown

Comment: @ShivamGupta , No that 'if else' statement is to fill the button with the last selected option so the user knows what database they're in, has nothing to do with the menu display

Comment: I removed the .filter , it was causing this problem. Thanks for the help, appreciate it! @ShivamGupta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.filter(item => !inputValue || item.value.includes(inputValue),)
```

To fix this problem, I removed the `.filter`,  It was causing only the selected value to show in the dropdown.

> This is the updated menu tag

```
 <Menu {...getMenuProps()}>
     {dropdownItems.map((item, index) => (
        <Item
            {...getItemProps({
                  key: item.value,
                 index,
                   item,
                      style: {
                  fontWeight:
                   index === highlightedIndex
                    ? 'bold'
                    : null,
                       },
                        })}
              >
          {item.value}
         </Item>
         ))}
          </Menu>
```